# Are \[ and \] needed?

Tags: linux, bash, xfce4

I see this bash prompt config from the internet:

`PS1="\[\e[0m\]\[\e[0;92m\]\u\[\e[91m\]@\[\e[93m\]\h\[\e[0m\]:\[\e[0;94m\]\w\[\033[1;30m\]\[\e[0m\]$ "`

As the document say:

> `\[` and `\]` are used to notice that the content inside is not printable (control characters).

When I strip out all the `\[` and `\]` from the prompt above, the `PS1` become:

`PS1="\e[0m\e[0;92m\u\e[91m@\e[93m\h\e[0m:\e[0;94m\w\033[1;30m\e[0m$ "`

And it still work! So, do the `\[` and `\]` needed? and what are the differents if I remove all them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried searching your history (<kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> or <kbd>↑</kbd>)? Once the line is longer, it can overwrite the prompt if it doesn't know its correct length.

Comment: I don't notice a difference unless there are history lines longer than the terminal width or with embedded new-line characters.

Comment: @AFH: That's it.

Comment: @grawity - the comment was more for the questioner's benefit: if he checked his history he would see no difference if he had only short lines in it.